# How to set items for JavaFX TableView - object contains another object?

Tags: javafx

i want to be short as possible without omitting useful information.
I have the following class:

```
public class Address{
StringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty();
StringProperty street = new SimpleStringProperty();

//following the constructor, getters and setters
...
}
```

I have another class Client, that one has an Address member

```
public class Client {

StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
StringProperty  id = new SimpleStringProperty();
ObjectProperty<Address> address = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

//following the constructor, getters and setters
...
}
```

and a JavaFX interface with a controller that contains a TableView object that should output in 3 column the members of the Client class and the city member of Address class for the given object. My TableView and TableColumn definition are the following code

```
public class SettingsController {
TableColumn<Client, String> clientNameCol;
TableColumn<Client, String> clientEmailCol;
TableColumn<Client, String> clientCityCol;
private TableView<Client> clientSettingsTableView;
...
...
    clientNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    clientNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client, String>("name"));

    clientEmailCol = new TableColumn<>("email");
    clientEmailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client, String>("email"));

    clientCityCol = new TableColumn<>("City");
    clientCityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client, String>("city"));

    clientSettingsTableView.setItems(clientData);
    clientSettingsTableView.getColumns().clear();
    clientSettingsTableView.getColumns().addAll(clientNameCol, clientEmailCol, clientCityCol);
```

and of course there is an ObservableList clientData that contains an array of Client object.
Everything  works fine except the column that should output the city for each client.
How should i define the column for the city (contained by an Address member) of Client object?

Comment: may be helpful http://fxapps.blogspot.com/2012/09/showing-object-properties-in-tableview.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@invariant thanks for your help, I googled a little bit more and i ended up with the following solution:

```
clientCityCol = new TableColumn<>("City");
clientCityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client, Address>("address"));
// ======== setting the cell factory for the city column  
clientCityCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Client, Address>, TableCell<Client, Address>>(){

        @Override
        public TableCell<Client, Address> call(TableColumn<Client, Address> param) {

            TableCell<Client, Address> cityCell = new TableCell<Client, Address>(){

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Address item, boolean empty) {
                    if (item != null) {
                        Label cityLabel = new Label(item.getCity());
                        setGraphic(cityLabel);
                    }
                }                    
            };               

            return cityCell;                
        }

    });
```

Address class has a getter getCity() which returns the city member as a String().

Comment: Really helped me @markus thanks +1.  This has to be a common design situation, but I find a sparsity of information on the web.  For all future visitors, isn't there something in the official documentation on this?

Comment: Just what i was looking, you can actually draw anything you want on updateItem

Answer (score 0):

This works in fxml?

Consider the following code:

`<TableColumn prefWidth="8" text="City">
    <cellValueFactory >
          <PropertyValueFactory property="adress.city" />
    </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>`

Working that way i have a blank cell.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think I just discovered a whole [other aspect](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm#CACHDCCF) of javafx fxml

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to mention that you have to change the definition of clientCityCol `TableColumn<Client, String> clientCityCol;` into `TableColumn<Client, Address> clientCityCol;` otherwise it won't work.